# ANLTR4: parse both integer and float

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANLTR4 to parse 2 types of expressions:

1. **pair expressions** are a pair of **integer or float** numbers, like `(1,2)` or `(1.0 , 2.0)`.
2. **single expressions** are a single **integer** `(1)`.

I designed my grammar like below but

- If I write `INT` before `NUM`, pair expressions with integers like `(1, 2)` can't be tokenized because of expecting a `NUM`;
- If I write `NUM` before `INT`, single expressions like `(1)` can't be tokenized because of expecting a `INT`.

```
grammar Expr;

prog   : single | pair ;
single : '(' INT ')' ;
pair   : '(' NUM ',' NUM ')' ;

INT   : [0-9]+ ;
NUM   : INT | FLOAT ;
FLOAT : '-'? INT '.' INT ;
WS    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```

To make both expressions be able to be tokenized, I can remove `NUM` lexer and manually write `pair` like:

```
pair : '(' INT   ',' INT   ')'
     | '(' INT   ',' FLOAT ')'
     | '(' FLOAT ',' INT   ')'
     | '(' FLOAT ',' FLOAT ')'
     ;
```

then both expressions can be parsed, and the pair expression supports both integers and floats.

But this is silly since if it's not pair but tuple10, it's impossible to write 1024 cases.

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Yes. Raise NUM to the parser level, `num : INT | FLOAT;  tuple10 : '(' num, num, num, ....... ')';`, and remove NUM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kaby76 already mentioned as a comment: promote `NUM` to a parser rule. It doesn't make a lot of sense to define `INT` and `FLOAT` in the lexer, and then define a `NUM` that makes the tokens `INT` and `FLOAT` never to become real tokens on their own.

```
prog   : single | pair ;
single : '(' INT ')' ;
pair   : '(' num ',' num ')' ;
num    : INT | FLOAT ;

INT    : [0-9]+ ;
FLOAT  : '-'? INT '.' INT ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```